# Settings In Express Node.js not clearly documented

Tags: node.js, express

I've been working with Express, and it seems like certain settings need to be set so that you can do things like have a template engine.  These seem like glorified global variables, and the only reference I've found to them is in the [using templates with express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#template-engines) documentation.

Is there a list of these settings somewhere?  How can I find out what settings are possible with Express?

Answer (score 0):

Settings found, and are [documented here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings).

Comment: One of my biggest gripes about Express (actually Connect, and I'm told the design came from Sinatra) is that `app.get()` is overloaded to mean two completely different things: to get a property/setting, and to setup a callback for an HTTP GET to a particular route.  IMO horrible.  (Though overall I like Express)

Comment: @user949300 There is talk of removing `app.get()` and `app.set()` in **Express 5**. https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2216